# c++ and mysql connector via Eclipse

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I want to connect to a MySQL database from a c++ program.  I've installed the mysql server and configured it. I've also installed a mysql c++ connector.

Everything is ok but I do not know how to include the libraries to the project so I can compile it. I use Eclipse Indigo with the C\C++ perspective.

The code for testing is it work I've got it from this site : 
[Connector example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html)

Comment: What platform?  (Windows, Linux, etc)  What version of the platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add an include directory (where your header files are located) then in the Eclipse menu go to Project->Properties then open the C/C++ Build branch and click on Settings.  On the right side click on the Directories branch of GCC C Compiler.  You can then add directories to your include path.